# How to test waterline models in Trails.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, waterline, trailsjs

I wanted to test the models of my Trails.js project with mocha. I use the [trailpack-waterline](https://github.com/trailsjs/trailpack-waterline) to load my models into the Waterline ORM.

Following the Trails [Docs](https://trailsjs.io/doc/en/test/unit.html#model-test-suite) I created a `User.test.js`:

```
'use strict'

const assert = require('assert')

describe('User Model', () => {
  let User

  before(() => {
    assert(global.app.models.User)
    User = global.app.models.User
  })

  it('should exist', () => {
    assert(User)
  })
})
```

This runs without any error.

But I cannot instantiate the model in any way. Following the example of the Docs `new User({...})` should create a new user object, but this code throws an error saying `User is not a constructor`. And neither the example of the Waterline [Docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing#?writing-tests) using `User.create({...})` seems to work.

Printing out the User model shows it consists of only two `methods: [ 'getModelName', 'getTableName' ]`.

How do I instantiate a waterline Model for unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `global.app.models.User` is your model's definition and not the waterline model. This one is under `global.app.orm.User`, after that you can use `User.create` without any problem